# Report parameters in MM/DD SSRS

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have a requirement where there will be two report parameters like From(MM/DD) and To(MM/DD) that will be used to compare against a month and day fields. For example, I have month and day fields stored in a table like

MM   DD

01   24

05   29

When the user enters the two report parameters values as say
From(01/25) and To(01/29), I need to retrieve records lies between Jan 25 to Jan 29 from the above table.

Can you kindly provide a sample way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to adjust the parameters in `ssrs` or `SQL` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle it in your query then you can simply use the `Left` and `Right` functions from sql server.

```
   Where 
      table.MM Between (Left(@FromParameter,2) AND Left(@ToParameter,2))
      AND table.DD Between (Right(@Paramter,2) AND Right(@ToParameter,2))
```

And if you want to pass the split value from the `SSRS` to your query then in dataset

**Dataset Properties -> Paramters-> Expression**

and for Frommonth parameter set the expression as

```
  = Left(Parameter!YourFromParamter.value,2)
```

for from day parameter set the expression as

```
  = Right(Parameter!YourFromParamter.value,2)
```

and for Tomonth parameter set the expression as

```
  = Left(Parameter!YourToParamter.value,2)
```

for to day parameter set the expression as

```
  = Right(Parameter!YourToParamter.value,2)
```

And pass these four paramters to query and in query use them with between

```
    WHERE
       table.MM BETWEEN @FromMonth AND @Tomonth
       AND table.DD BETWEEN @FromDay AND @ToDay
```